# I need more information about PowerPAK-SO8 thermal properties than i can find online

Tags: mosfet, heat, thermal, powermosfet, cooling

There are these MOSFETs in PowerPAK-SO8 (Vishay) package (or SuperSO8 for Infineon). I used to cool them from the outside, attaching a heatsink to the black (plastic? ceramic?) case worked pretty well. However, I need to support this with some numbers, and I can't find any thermal model of the MOSFET.

Ideally, I would want the tetha between the die and the outer surface.

https://www.vishay.com/docs/71622/71622.pdf

[image]

Comment: If there's no spec listed, you'd have to contact the manufacturer. It's likely they didn't measure it, though, if it's not listed; measuring thermal impedance is relatively involved. If you're a big enough customer, you can probably convince them to measure it, but otherwise you're out of luck. Incidentally, are you sure it's ceramic? This doesn't seem like an expensive enough package to be ceramic rather than plastic...

Comment: I am not sure, actually just guessing. I'll edit the question for it to be just black :) Yes, I don't expect them to measure for me. My thought was to try and estimate thermal resistance, but I don't know which material is it.

Comment: You should be able to derive it from figure 5.

Comment: I don't believe it's related... Perhaps if I wouldn't attach a heatsink. It's 30-40 K/W, while in reality I see something close to 3-7 K/W.

Comment: Ceramic packages tend to only be used on the most expensive parts where they can't be avoided, because they're far more expensive than plastic packages. Unless you're paying $20 or more for each one of these parts, it's almost certainly a plastic package. I've never seen a surface-mount ceramic package, either (unless you count those weird RF packages with the low-inductance flat leads, I suppose).

Comment: Well.. I really can't tell the difference if there is no price tag attached ;) anyway, all i can find online is a very broad range of values with my expectation falling somewhere in the middle. Like i measure 30 degrees rise, and with the data i see it could be anything between 0.5 and 1000 degrees